# node-mysql implodes without doing anything

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am trying to simply connect to a mysql db, then close the connection. My code is basically taken straight from node-mysql's guide.

```
require('fs').readFile('/etc/mysql/mysql-ssl-ca-cert.pem','utf8',function(err,caFile){
    if(err){
        console.error(err);
    }else{
        var connection = require('mysql').createConnection({
            host     : 'localhost',
            user     : 'root',
            password : 'password',
            ssl      : { ca : caFile }
        });
        connection.connect(function(err){
            if(err){
                console.error(err);
            }else{
                console.log('connected');
            }
        });
        connection.end(function(err) { if(err) console.error('Error On DB Close.'); });
    }
});
```

I get the 'connected' message but then everything crashes, triggered by an uncaught error exception, what did I do wrong?

backtrace:

```
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: shutdown ENOTCONN
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at Socket.onSocketFinish (net.js:232:26)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:104:17)
    at finishMaybe (_stream_writable.js:484:14)
    at endWritable (_stream_writable.js:493:3)
    at Socket.Writable.end (_stream_writable.js:459:5)
    at Socket.end (net.js:407:31)
    at Protocol.<anonymous> (/Users/camdennarzt/Developer/JS/barcoding/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:85:27)
    at Protocol.emit (events.js:129:20)
    at Protocol.end (/Users/camdennarzt/Developer/JS/barcoding/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:99:10)
```

Comment: I thought that I should stick everything in the connect callback originally, however that raises the same error, so I changed things to more closely match the documentation and the error still happens.

Comment: You're right, that's the correct usage of .end. Once you're connected, are you able to successfully query the database?

Comment: I can query, and get correct results. It just crashes when I try and use `.end(...)`.

Comment: Wrapping `.end(...)` in a try block doesn't help, I get the same error; and not calling `.end(...)` doesn't help, everything just hangs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a bug in node or node-mysql. See https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/issues/1027